# Returning PDF from ASP.NET Web API crashes IE

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm using an httpresponsemessage to display files through Web API. If I use content disposition type attachment I have no problems. I've been asked to have them open directly in the browser (disposition type attachment). I simply changed the type to inline and everything works fine in every browser except IE. I get an "Internet explorer has encountered an error and needs to close" error when I try to use IE.

Here's the code I'm using

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        byte[] filebytes = null;

                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(strPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length);
                }
            response.Headers.Clear();
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(filebytes);
            CacheControlHeaderValue cch = new CacheControlHeaderValue();
            cch.Private = true;
            response.Headers.CacheControl = cch;
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = filebytes.Length;
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue ch = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            ch.FileName = "Document.pdf";
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = ch;


        return response;
```

What I've tried:

- Adding date created headers
- Using a stream instead of a byte array
- Removing the private cache control header. I added this because of an issue I was having with windows XP machines not displaying files. Even when I remove the cache control header completely I still have the issue. This is not the problem.
- Clearing out the headers first, and not clearing out the headers first

Any suggestions?

Comment: In similar situations I have found that the problem is not the browser so much as the version of the PDF plugin and its configuration that the browser in question is using.

Comment: I'm using ie 10 and haven't installed any plugins since windows updated me. Could it have to do with the version of Acrobat on my computer and the way it interacts with the browser?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but yes, the installed version of Acrobat can influence this.  Complicating things a bit further (at least in terms of keeping the details straight in one's head) Chrome has its own native PDF reader: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142056 which may or may not be in use based on configuration.  Hope that helps.